# Unclear graphics in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: graphics, firefox, google-chrome, pdf, visual-artifacts

When I try to use Firefox or Google Chrome browser or PDF reader, I cannot read the text properly. The characters are unclear (see screenshots). I have already installed the Intel G31 graphics driver in my Ubuntu 15.10, but I'm still facing this problem.

```
:~$ uname -a  
Linux prashant-OEM 4.2.0-25-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 12:31:50 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

[image]
<sup>(Click images to enlarge)  **PDF reader**</sup>

[image]
<sup>**Google Chrome**</sup>

Comment: Which kernel do you use? Please update your question with `uname -a` command results.

Comment: It looks like a graphics issue, maybe the wrong graphics driver. You can identify the correct graphics driver from the terminal before you install it, after you have installed it the same command can give false results. Anyway the command to identify the recommended graphics driver before you have installed it is `ubuntu-drivers devices`

Comment: Could you also add results of the `lspci -nn|grep VGA` command, and post your `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` somewhere?